# What exactly does setListAdapter do?

Tags: android

I'm debugging an Android program that I didn't write so a lot of this is trying to figure out how it's intended to work.

It has a ListActivity, and one of the members of the ListActivity is a ListView called lv.  I'm trying to track how lv gets populated as it's being initialized in *onCreate()*.   I added a couple of lines to look at in the debugger here . . .

```
mylistadapter = new MyListAdapter(myListActivity.this);
int lvCount = lv.getCount();  // for debugging only - delete before releasing
setListAdapter(mylistadapter);
lvCount = lv.getCount();  // for debugging only - delete before releasing
```

... and what I can see is that lvCount is 0 before calling *setListAdapter()*, and then 15 after calling it.

But Google's documentation on it just says,

> public void **setListAdapter** (ListAdapter adapter)
>
> Provide the cursor for the list view.

Which does't really tell me very much.   Could someone please explain in more detail what that means and how it explains the result I'm seeing?

Additional Information

```
mylistadapter = new MyListAdapter(MyListActivity.this);
```

and

```
   protected class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
   . . .
```

Comment: see  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

Comment: The `Adapter` is essentially what translates the data which is supposed to be displayed into `Views` that actually can be displayed.

Comment: @njzk2 that list doesn't contain a definition for the call either.   I'm not looking for an example; I'm looking for a definition.

Comment: Xaver Kapeller - I know what an adapter is but I'm trying to understand what that call does and how it results in the ListView's count changing.  If I set a breakpoint in the adapter's getView() it does not get called in between when lv is 0 and lv is 15.   So what exactly is setListAdapter doing that causes that result?

Comment: why would getView have been called? the ui thread is still in your method. I suggest you take a look at the source code for ListView.getCount

Comment: Would people who are downvoting this please explain why?  If you think this is well-documented somewhere then a link would be more constructive.

Comment: @njzk2 - I don't understand your answer -  I'm trying to understand setListAdapter.  To learn to program Android is it really necessary to study the underlying Android source code?  I don't even know where to find that.

Answer (score 0):

The ListView gets its count from the MyListAdapter Object. MyListAdapter should implement a `getCount()`- method somewhere. thats where the number 15 is coming from. and its 0 before you set the adapter, because there is no adapter. Does that help?

EDIT:
Heres a Link to the ArrayAdapter Docs:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html
My Guess is that MyListAdapter inherits from ArrayAdapter, but if it does not let me know.

In response to aadditional information:
Heres a link to the Adapter-Docs:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html
Thats the class MyListAdapter inherits the `getCount()` method from. Its an interface that ist implemented in the BaseAdapter-class.

In response to comment:
as per the documentation, `lv.getCount()` returns

```
The number of items owned by the Adapter associated with this AdapterView. (This is the number of data items, which may be larger than the number of visible views.)
```

So basically it just calls the adpaters `getCount()`, and returns 0 if there is no adapter.
(ListView inherits `getCount()`from AdapterView)
Link to the docs:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getCount%28%29

Comment: I've added some more detail to the question.   MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter.   When you say " it should implement a getCount()" I'm not sure what you mean by "it".   The Adapter implements a getCount() but that's not the getCount() that gets called for lv - ListView has its own getCount().  Should I be overriding it?

Comment: if I set a breakpoint in my override of the Adapter's _getCount()_ it does not get hit for either of the calls to lv.getCount(), but it **DOES** get hit for the call to _setListAdapter()_, in between them.  So why do you say that the ListView's _getCount()_ is just calling the Adapter's one? (I do see in the class hierarchy that Listview itself inherits from AdapterView)

Comment: @user316117 - i dont know what to tell you here. Even if `lv.getCount()`doesn't call the adapters `getCount()`every time, it is pretty clear that the count gets stored on the ListViews internal fields when you call `setAdapter()`, and it gets updated whenever you call the Adpaters `notifyDataSetChanged()' method to indicate that the data was updated. but this is just android trying to optimize things.  Its really starting to get to the point where i need to ask "what do you need this for?" if you want a good answer...